# How to make onChange tracking function in functional component as in class component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Here is my class component

```
handleChange =(e) => {
   this.setState({
       [e.target.id]: e.target.value
   })
}

<div className="input-field">
            <label htmlFor="email">Email</label>
            <input type="email" id="email" onChange={this.handleChange}/>
 </div>
 <div className="input-field">
            <label htmlFor="password">Password</label>
            <input type="password" id="password" onChange={this.handleChange}/>
 </div>
```

As you can see we can track all the input with one function component.

But how to get the same result as that inside the functional component?
Now I am setting state for each element.

```
<div className="input-field">
          <label htmlFor="email">Email</label>
          <input type="email" id="email" onChange={e =>setEmail(e.target.value)}/>
       </div>
 <div className="input-field">
          <label htmlFor="password">Password</label>
          <input type="password" id="password" onChange={e => setPassword(e.target.value)}/>
 </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The update is similar. Given some state, `data` for example, then a handler may look like:

```
const handleChange = (e) => {
  const { id, value } = e.target;
  setData((data) => ({
    ...data,
    [id]: value
  }));
};
```

Use a functional state update to spread in the existing state and use the input's id and value from the `onChange` event to update that section of state.

[image: Edit how-to-make-onchange-tracking-function-in-functional-component-as-in-class-compo]

Full code example

```
function App() {
  const [data, setData] = useState({});

  const handleChange = (e) => {
    const { id, value } = e.target;
    setData((data) => ({
      ...data,
      [id]: value
    }));
  };

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <div className="input-field">
        <label htmlFor="email">Email</label>
        <input type="email" id="email" onChange={handleChange} />
      </div>
      <div className="input-field">
        <label htmlFor="password">Password</label>
        <input type="password" id="password" onChange={handleChange} />
      </div>

      <div>Email: {data.email}</div>
      <div>Password: {data.password}</div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
const [input, setInput] = useState({email:"", password:""})

<div className="input-field">
            <label htmlFor="email">Email</label>
            <input type="email" id="email" value={input.email} 
            onChange={e => setInput({...input,[e.target.id]: e.target.value}}/>
 </div>
 <div className="input-field">
            <label htmlFor="password">Password</label>
            <input type="password" id="password" value={input.password} 
             onChange={e => setInput({...input,[e.target.id]: e.target.value}}/>
 </div>
```

You can try this code.
In this way you can handle both inputs using same state without handler

Comment: OP wants a single handler for both inputs. Setting a `value` prop to one of them doesn't address issue of using one handler.

Answer (score 1):

declare one state containing both email and pasword for your functional component as below :

```
let [loginInfo, setLoginInfo] = useState({email:'',password:''})

handleChange =(e) => {
    setLoginInfo({
       ...loginInfo,
       [e.target.id]: e.target.value
    })    

}
```

you form

```
<div className="input-field">
    <label htmlFor="email">Email</label>
    <input type="email" id="email" onChange={handleChange}/>
     </div>
<div className="input-field">
    <label htmlFor="password">Password</label>
    <input type="password" id="password" onChange={handleChange}/>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can create object of form input and assign it to a state like below

```
const [formInput, setFormInput] = useState({
    email: "",
    password: ""
  });
```

And set it like this

```
const handleChange = (e) => {
    setFormInput((prevState) => ({
      ...prevState,
      [e.target.id]: e.target.value
    }));
  };
```

See this codesandbox [code](https://codesandbox.io/s/musing-cloud-xytm6?file=/src/App.js)